# How can I get a facebook user metadata by calling the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, curl, graph

I registered my app at the App Dashboard. I got an app ID and an app secret code on the app dashboard.

Then I was able to generate a bearer access token:

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={MY_APP_ID}&client_secret={MY_APP_CLIENT_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Then I try to get the metadata with call:

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{AN_ID_OF_A_USER}?metadata=1&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN_GENERATED}"
```

Unfortunately the later call works only with my own user ID, and not with any other user IDs. I get an error message with other user IDs:

```
{"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request. Object with ID '12345678910' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"error_subcode":33,"fbtrace_id":"xXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxX"}}
```

What should I do or set, and where to be able to get metadata of other users? I would like to be interested in the relationship status of specific users, to get this metadata field programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get IDs of users who did not authorize your App, and there is no way to get any other data of users without authorization. So if the user in question did not authorize your App, he will be completely unavailable.

Comment: Oh, I see. However I can view those data by opening the user page in a browser.

Comment: it does not matter if you can open a user page in the browser, an app does not have any access to a user without authorization - for example, to prevent app developers from automating things like storing user details and whatnot.